# Прошивка BIOS HP Pavilion 9350EG

Tags: hp, bios

Ноутбук HP Pavilion HDX 9350EG. 
Был прошит BIOS, видимо не той прошивкой или что-то пошло не так. В итоге ноутбук запускается, ну в общем только включиться он и может, далее шум вентиляторов(экран не срабатывает). 
 Резерв bios на hdd не нашел. Точнее его там нету. Зашел на сайт производителя, предлагает вариант, загрузить его ПО->слить прошивку через ПО на флэшку->вставить->зажать WIN+B и ждать. ПО так и запустить не смог, требует WMI и ещё какие-то фрэймворки. Варьировал варианты типа: прошивки в виде 068.BIN на флэшку, в подкаталоги HP, hp tools, разные флэшки, всё это пихал в USB пациента, зажимал WIN+B, результат один, капс мигает, флэшку толи видет толи не видит. Горела постоянно одним цветом(как такового чтения/записи не было). Теперь правда и вовсе не горит. 
 Думаю программатором шить, да вот только на плате не могу найти чип.
 Подскажите что делать.

Comment: сколько раз капсом мигает?

Comment: Боюсь, проблемы с железом у нас тут на грани оффтопика.

Comment: постоянно, с равным интервалом. (соответственно мигает  после запуска при зажатом WIN+B)

Comment: VladD, поясните

Comment: если токо при WIN+B- не то, многие hp умеют капсом неисправность показывать(n раз через паузу, где n проц, биос, графика и т.д.). Пробуй полный сброс(аккум, батарейка), если нет, программатором. Чип вот так выглядит - http://www.bios-chip24.com/epages/63730052.sf/ru_RU/?ObjectPath=/Shops/63730052/Products/16186